# Velocity sensitive fluid free hand drawing brush in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying a code a html5 canvas drawing app, similar to chrome canvas or the drawing section of google keep. However I am stuck here trying a create a fluid free hand drawing brush, which simulates pressure sensitivity ( ie the brush strokes have dynamic width through their length )

I tried to change the stroke lineWidth property proportional to mouse speed on mousemove event...but there are just too many points with radical jumps in width, and it doesn't look smooth at all.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated. I've been stuck on it for 2 days now